# Spring Social - Not Redirected to SignUp Page after Successful Login

Tags: spring, spring-social

Let me start by saying that I am a newcomer to Spring and Spring Social. I've managed to get social network authentication up and running to the point where as user can click on "Login With Twitter", they are redirected to the Twitter login page and after logging in with their credentials, they are redirected back to my application.

However, when they get back to my application, they are not taken to the SignUp screen, but instead back to the login screen. Below is my SocialConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSocial
public class SocialConfig implements SocialConfigurer {

    @Inject
    private DataSource dataSource;

    //
    // SocialConfigurer implementation methods
    //

    @Override
    public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer cfConfig, Environment env) {
        cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(new TwitterConnectionFactory("<api-key>", "<secret-key>"));
    }

    @Override
    public UserIdSource getUserIdSource() {
        return new UserIdSource() {
            @Override
            public String getUserId() {
                Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
                if (authentication == null) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to get a ConnectionRepository: no user signed in");
                }
                return authentication.getName();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public UsersConnectionRepository getUsersConnectionRepository(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {
        return new JdbcUsersConnectionRepository(dataSource, connectionFactoryLocator, Encryptors.noOpText());
    }

    //
    // API Binding Beans
    //

    @Bean
    @Scope(value="request", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public Facebook facebook(ConnectionRepository repository) {
        Connection<Facebook> connection = repository.findPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class);
        return connection != null ? connection.getApi() : null;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value="request", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public Twitter twitter(ConnectionRepository repository) {
        Connection<Twitter> connection = repository.findPrimaryConnection(Twitter.class);
        return connection != null ? connection.getApi() : null;
    }

    //
    // Web Controller and Filter Beans
    //
    @Bean
    public ConnectController connectController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        ConnectController connectController = new ConnectController(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);
        return connectController;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProviderSignInController providerSignInController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository) {
        return new ProviderSignInController(connectionFactoryLocator, usersConnectionRepository, new SimpleSignInAdapter(new HttpSessionRequestCache()));
    }

    @Bean
    public ReconnectFilter apiExceptionHandler(UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository, UserIdSource userIdSource) {
        return new ReconnectFilter(usersConnectionRepository, userIdSource);
    }

}
```

I've also created the UserConnection table in my database, and I see from the logs that when a user logs into Twitter for example, it does a read from this table, but does not write anything to this table.

Can someone please help me get this working?

EDIT:

1. I've read the following in the Spring Social docs: "If any error occurs when exchanging the request token for an access token or while fetching the user's profile data, ProviderSignInController will redirect to the application's sign in URL. The request to the sign in URL will have an "error" query parameter set to "provider" to indicate an error occurred while communicating with the provider." - this is what is happening in my application. How do I debug this?